# Getting information from a private class inside a public method

Tags: c#

I have the following.

```
public static class Foo()
{
    private class Bar()
    {
        public float x;
        public float y;
        public float z;
        //... many more properties....
        
    }
    private static _bar = new Bar()

    // Need other classes to be able to get x, y, z
}
```

I know it is a somewhat strange methodology, but the API I am interfacing with (Unity) requires that Bar() be an empty class (cannot inherit from anything and no functions, nor can it be a static class) of only public fields.  For proper accessibility, I don't want other classes to be able to see this class as there is no need to create more than one.  So, I put the class inside the static class that utilizes it and create a singleton of sorts (there are static functions that will be in this class that interact with the singleton).

I will have situations where I need to access data from that singleton.

I have tried a basic `GetBar()` that returns `_bar` but the compiler does not let me do this (which makes sense, other classes wouldn't understand the type being returned).  Thus, my only real solution is to make a bunch of `GetX()`, `GetY()`, etc. for every variable that I add to Bar().  This would work, but I would consider it poor practice if it can be avoided since now I need to make sure I manually add a Get() function every time I add a new property (which is messy).

I cannot make _bar public without making Bar() public and then any class could create an instance of Bar() which I don't want.

Is there any way to automate getting the public properties of a private class that is within a public static class?

Comment: For proper accessibility, I don't want other classes to be able to see this class - but you better to make it visible and forget about the strange problem you created

Comment: The question isn't necessarily about getting things to work, it's about producing optimal code.  I know that making it public will work, as would generating a getter/setter for every individual property of the singleton in the static class, but it goes against basic accessibility optimization and results in messy spaghetti code that is better avoided IF possible.  It may not be possible, but I thought it worth checking and see if I can learn something new.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean anything bad. I just never seen  that somebody  was placing private classes inside of the public, especially static.

Comment: It is certainly strange.  It's one of those "there's probably a better way to organize the project" but unfortunately much of the project exists outside of my personal scope.  As I said, I can't make Bar() anything other than an empty, non-static class without functions which is highly limiting.

Comment: Try to code as simple as possible, but not more simple. Don't invent anything  during your first 10 years of work.

Comment: It has a look like there should be a better way to do this, but for that I would have to see more of the app. As for your exact question the interface answer by Dmitry Bychenko is probably the cleanest, though now you need to remember to add the new property to the interface.

Answer (score 0):

This really strange architecture. I'm not sure I understood the problem correctly, but I can offer a classic implementation of Singleton pattern:

```
public static class Foo
{
    public class FooBar
    {
        // Will work
        private float x = Bar.GetInstance().x;

        // Will not work
        private Bar bar = new Bar();
        private float y = Bar.y;
    }
}

public sealed class Bar
{
    public float x;
    public float y;
    public float z;

    private static Bar _instance;

    // You can call the constructor only from Bar class
    private Bar() { }

    // Use this method to access Bar fields
    public static Bar GetInstance()
    {
        // If Bar called first time it creates new instance
        if (_instance == null) _instance = new Bar();

        // If Bar instance was created use old instance
        return _instance;
    }
}
```

And about:

> Thus, my only real solution is to make a bunch of GetX(), GetY(), etc.
> for every variable that I add to Bar(). This would work, but I would
> consider it poor practice if it can be avoided since now I need to
> make sure I manually add a Get() function every time I add a new
> property (which is messy).

You can use auto-property like:

```
public float X { get; set; }
```

This automatically create private field with accessors.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *conceal* the *implementation* (class `Bar`), but have an access to *interface* (i.e. `x, y, z`)
you can *extract interface* required:

```
// Interface we want to have access to
public IBar {
  float x {get; set;}
  float y {get; set;}
  float z {get; set;}
}
```

then

```
public static class Foo() {
  // now Bar implements IBar
  private class Bar : IBar {
    // turn fields into properties which can be accessed via IBar interface
    public float x {get; set;}
    public float y {get; set;}
    public float z {get; set;}
    //... many more properties....
        
  }

  // Now other classes are able to get x, y, z:
  // bar is public and it is of public interface IBar 
  public static readonly IBar bar = new Bar();
}
```